# How to do RandomBug code

Tags: java, eclipse, random, gridworld

no idea how to fix this code. Need to do the runner and the main class. The program needs to be able to randomly generate the bug's turns.

**This is what i have for my RandomBug class so far:**

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
import java.awt.Color;
public class RandomBug extends Bug
{
  public RandomBug()
  {
    setColor(Color.YELLOW);
  }

  public RandomBug(Color bugColor)
  {
    setColor(bugColor);
  }

  public void turn(int angle)
  {
      turn(); turn(); turn(); turn();
  }

  public void turnAround() {
      turn();
} 
  public int turnAngle() {
    int angle = 45 * (int) (Math.random() * 8);
    int x = angle;
    return x;
  }
  public void act()
  {

    if (canMove())
        move();
    else
        turnAround();    
  }  
}
```

**And this is my RandomBugRunner.java:**

```
import java.awt.Color;

import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

public class RandomBugRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
        RandomBug bug1 = new RandomBug();
        bug1.setColor(Color.blue);
        world.add(bug1);
        bug1.act();
        bug1.turn(bug1.turnAngle());
        bug1.turnAround();
        world.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what happens when you run it?  That would really help :)  Also you should announce that this is for homework.

Comment: Not sure if this is intended, but `Math.random()` returns a value in the range [0,1), so you could get an angle of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `act` function, it calls `turnAround` which then just calls `turn`, never calling turnAngle() at all.  In addition, `turn(int angle)` seems to ignore the angle entirely.  As this is clearly homework, I don't want to just give you the answer, but I hope this puts you on the right track :)